# ADODB types not showing up in Access

Tags: ms-access, ado

I'm in Access 2007 and added the Reference(s): Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.8 Library & Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects Recordset 2.8 Library but when I type ADODB. I don't get the Command type or Connection type. All that shows up are the enum definitions. What am I missing? Why am I not getting the Command, Connection, and other actual types?

Comment: `Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset` yesno? You should not need ActiveX Data Objects Recordset 2.8 Library

Comment: Hmm, yeah that works. What's the difference?

Comment: I have no idea what you tried, so I cannot say what is the difference.

Comment: Dim oQry
Set oQry = new ADODB.Command

Comment: That is incorrect syntax for VBA.